# CSS/HTML Align divs horizontally

Tags: css, alignment

So i need divs to align horizontally and fill blank spaces left in previous row's like so:

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/eqrudv.jpg]

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Is it only the leftmost column that should be filled?

Answer (score 6):

There's no way of doing this automatically with pure CSS, but Javascript can help you. There is a good library called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Glad to hear it; welcome to StackOverflow. Click the tick next to the answer to mark it as the correct answer.